# My text is overflowing Pixels, how can I fix that and how do I increase the size of image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**I have tried using Expanded and Flexible and none of it is working.I am not able to understand why.Also is this the best way to increase the size of image, because I want that my images looks size looks same across all devices.**

```
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: size.width * 0.4,
                    height: size.width * 0.6,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('images/brushOne.jpg'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Thank you for letting me do what I love, your support is contagious If I could put all 10,000 of you in a room and give you all a hug I WOULD. Your support makes my heart grow and glow. Thank you for helping me create a business and a family.I love you all ',
                      
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
```

[image]

Comment: for the text, you could wrap it in a Flexible() widget

Comment: Wrap that Padding widget into Flexible widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.fill)),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
          child: Text(
            'Thank you for letting me do what I love, your support is contagious If I could put all 10,000 of you in a room and give you all a hug I WOULD. Your support makes my heart grow and glow. Thank you for helping me create a business and a family.I love you all ',
          ),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

You set the first container to 40%.
**width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4**
If you set the width of the *second* container to 60%,
**width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6**
the problem will be solved. You can use sizedbox() to leave space between two containers if you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Engin Yammer for helping me out with your crisp and clear answer.  :))

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the padding widget fixed the problem:

[image]

[image]

The difference is the constraints passed to Text.

With Expanded, the constraints is fixed size:
[image]

Without Expanded, the constraints is infinity:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use ,

```
        SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: Text(
              "Thank you for letting me do what I love, your support is contagious If I could put all 10,000 of you in a room and give you all a hug I WOULD. Your support makes my heart grow and glow. Thank you for helping me create a business and a family.I love you all ",
              maxLines: 5,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanded should work as demoed in this quick mock-up [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=66c3fe15ee0e3b9b163bb51d54c1615f&null_safety=true).

Like Engin has mentioned MediaQuery is your best bet for scaling contents to a device's screen, but if you're applying MediaQuery to both sections of the Row, you'll have to update both sizes each time you choose to resize one element. This is accruing unnecessary technical debt that will compound if you ever choose to add additional elements to the Row in the future. Expanded on the other hand will take up the remaining space without the need to manually calculate sizes each time you make a change to UI elements.